# How to enable implicit type conversion from non-const to const in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

Here's the essence of the code:

```
class DM
{
public:
    int something;
    DM() : something(0) { }
};

typedef DM * dm_t;
typedef dm_t & dm_ref_t;
typedef const DM * dm_const_t;
typedef dm_const_t & dm_cref_t;

int getSomething( dm_cref_t dm ) // CALLING getSomething DOES NOT COMPILE
{
    return dm->something;
}

int getSomethingAgain( dm_const_t dm )
{
    return dm->something;
}

int getSomethingOnceMore( dm_ref_t dm )
{
    return dm->something;
}

int main()
{
    dm_t dm = new DM;
    getSomething( dm ); // COMPILER ERROR COMES FROM HERE
    getSomethingAgain( dm );
    getSomethingOnceMore( dm );
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the compiler error:

```
implicit_cast.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
implicit_cast.cpp:31: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const DM*&’ from expression of type ‘DM*’
implicit_cast.cpp:13: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘int getSomething(const DM*&)’
```

That is, I have a non-const pointer that I'd like to pass into a function that accept a const pointer by reference. All is fine and dandy if the function would accept a non-const pointer by reference or a const pointer by value, but const pointer by reference does not accept non-const pointer.

For safety reasons I'd like the function to take a const pointer; for some further development reasons I'd like it to be passed by reference. It should be completely safe to automatically cast from non-const to const. Why doesn't g++ performs the cast?

I'd like to proceed further with a function defined like getSomething. How can I legalize these calls without adding explicit casts every time I call it?

Comment: The simplest answer is: don't use pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB: this is kind of what I'm doing now. :) I inherited large piece of pointer-rich code, and trying to smoothly transition to objects. First by typedef the pointers, then replace typedef with a class. Less chances to screw up by transitioning in steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like the C++ name "resolution". In your case, you have a pointer to a `const DM`, but you want a const pointer, so you must use `typedef dm_const_t const & dm_cref_t` (a const reference to a const pointer)

Giving more details:

When you declare `const int * a`, you are saying that `a` is a constant pointer to an integer. It is the same as `int const * a`.

If you want a reference to a type, you declare `int & b`, meaning that `b` is a reference to an integer. Thinking the same way, `const int & c` is the same as `int const & c` (const always qualify the *variable*, not the type).

So, if you want a const reference to a const pointer, using the second notation is clearer (and the only one possible if not using `typedef`s): `int const * const & d`, meaning `d` is a constant reference to a constant pointer to an integer. Using typedefs:

```
typedef const int * int_cptr;
typedef const int_cptr & int_cptrcref;
```

Proof: http://ideone.com/V48Kxe

Comment: Although this might solve this problem, it is not a recommended thing to do, since you already have a const pointer, then you won't have access to change it, then the const reference is not needed (creating a copy of a pointer is as expensive as copying an integer or maybe even using a reference - so no reference to a const pointer is needed).

Comment: Isn't `<type> const *ptr` a mutable pointer to const data, and `<type> * const ptr` a const pointer to mutable data?

Answer (score 4):

It's not doing it because, after expanding the typedefs, you have

```
int getSomething( DM const* & dm )
{
  return dm->something;
}
...
int main()
{
  DM* dm = new DM;
  getSomething( dm );
}
```

g++ is correctly NOT allowing this automatically, because you are asking for a non-const lvalue reference to a constant pointer.   You currently have a non-constant pointer.  It can't create a temporary, since the temporary can't bind to the non-const lvalue reference.

Now, if you were to take the pointer by constant reference, it would work, since it would be allowed to bind to the temporary.  However, I would just pass the pointer directly, since there is no value in passing a pointer by constant reference.

The reason why this isn't allow is because if it were, so would this (defeating the purpose of the `const` system)

```
const int i = 5;
void foo( const int* & p)
{
   p = &i;
}

void bar()
{
   int * p; 
   foo(p); // Normally not legal
   *p = 6; // And this is why
}
```

Now, all that being said, any time I see a reference to a pointer my first question to the developer is why they needed to do that.  Occasionally, it's because you need to have an output parameter, but it's not something I would expect to be widespread.

Comment: This is a very subtle but valid observation. However I think it would be more clear if `const int i = 5;` were global (or at least static), as the above code suffers a perhaps more severe issue at the line `*p = 6;` that is this line writes to memory no longer on the stack rather than "merely" writing to something that was supposed to be const as I believe was your intent.

Comment: @Apriori: You're right. Updated to be global, as I meant the constant to be the issue, not the local variable scope.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `[conv.qual]` (4.4/4) in the C++11 standard:

> A conversion can add cv-qualifiers at levels other than the first in
>   multi-level pointers, subject to the following rules: ... [Note: if a
>   program could assign a pointer of type T** to a pointer of type const
>   T** (that is, if line #1 below were allowed), a program could
>   inadvertently modify a const object (as it is done on line #2).

The example given is:

```
int main() {
    const char c = ’c’;
    char* pc;
    const char** pcc = &pc; // #1: not allowed
    *pcc = &c;
    *pc = ’C’; // #2: modifies a const object
}
```

This is explained for pointers to pointers, but the same applies for references to pointers for exactly the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

You are passing by pointer which can mean that after function execution there could be two different references to the same memory, one declared const, one declared non-const.

If the non-const reference is used to change the memory then the const reference suddenly has its underlying memory would suddenly have become changed, which would be incorrect behavior.